# Java operands usage

Tags: java

```
int a = 3;
int b = (a=2)*a;
int c = b * (b=5);
System.out.println("a=" + a + " b=" + b + " c=" + c);
```

Can someone explain me why the output is:

```
a=2 b=5 c=20
```

instead of

```
a=2 b=4 c=20
```

Answer (score 2):

Because [assignment is an operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) which [returns the new value it set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850676/return-value-of-assignment-operator) and, while it's normally last in precedence,  the parentheses move it up before the non-parenthetical operators. Think of it like this:

1. `a` is set to 3.
2. `a` is set to 2, returning 2. That is then multiplied by the *new* value of `a`, which is 2, setting `b` to 4.
3. 4 (old `b`) is multiplied by the result of `b=5`, which is 5. `b` is now 5, and `c` is set to the `4x5` value (20).

Answer (score 1):

You have reassigned `b` to a 5 in the second statement. As a result `b` will be 5 until it is assigned again. What part of this is confusing you?

Comment: Oh now I get it. I forgot about the second assignment. Such a stupid question I've asked..

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning 5 to b, in the third line. So, that's what it contains.

Comment: @Cruncher I don't think it's assignment as comparison just a misunderstanding of scope

Comment: @inquisitiveIdiot Oh, I didn't even look that close. I just saw `b=5` inside of an expression and sort of assumed

Answer (score 1):

b is 5 because of this (b=5);

a is 2 because  of this (a=2)

c is 20  because  of this 4 * (b=5);