# Java assignment operator behavior vs C++

Tags: java, c++, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

This occured while I was tackling a 'Cracking the Coding interview' question:

> Write a function to swap a number in place (that is, without temporary variables)

I decided to write up my solution in Java (because I plan on using Java in my internship interviews.)

I came up with a solution that I was almost confident was the right answer (because I did it in one line):

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int a = 5;
        int b = 7;
        a = b - a + (b = a);
        System.out.println("a: " + a + " b: " + b);
    }
```

Surely enough, this code executes the desired result. `a == 7` and `b == 5`.

**Now here's the funny part.**

This code won't run in C++ nor is this solution in the back of the book.

So my question is: Why exactly does my solution work? I am assuming Java does things differently than other languages?

Comment: Hint: xor ...........

Comment: I think (b = a) doesn't return anything in C++. Or maybe I'm wrong, I don't know C++.

Comment: For java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850676/return-value-of-assignment-operator

Comment: For c++: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292892/what-is-return-type-of-assignment-operator

Comment: @Sweeper `b = a` is evaluated to an lvalue of `b`, with the side effect of assignment.

Comment: @Sweeper As an expression, it yields the value assigned .. however, C/C++ have the 'fun' issue of sequence points and thus Undefined Behavior. In Java it's defined behavior, albeit 'too clever for me'.

Comment: @NickyC I know that, in Java at least. But I don't think C++ has that feature

Comment: @Sweeper I am mentioning C++.

Comment: Search for and read about *sequence points* (I also recommend [this evaluation-order reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks at the [Java Language Specification, section 15.7 (Evaluation Order)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7):

> The Java programming language guarantees that the operands of
>   operators appear to be evaluated in a specific evaluation order,
>   namely, from left to right.

So in Java the evaluation order is well-defined and does what you expect.

The C++ specification doesn't provide such a guarantee; in fact it's Undefined Behavior so the program could literally do anything.

Quoting from the [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order), noting that no sequencing rule exists for sequencing operands to arithmetic operators:

> If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to a value
>   computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is
>   undefined.

Comment: In contrast, "If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined." ([cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order)), noting that no sequencing rule exists for sequencing operands to arithmetic operators.